# Deny certain IP's

Tags: apache

I need to deny certain IP's all access but I can't see any deny.
I put this code on my ssl.conf inside label VirtualHost

```
<LocationMatch "/.*">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        SetEnvif X-Forwarded-For "93\.176\.144\.153" DenyAccess
        SetEnvif X-Forwarded-For "139\.162\.206\.138" DenyAccess
        Deny from env=DenyAccess
</LocationMatch>
```

Why not run correctly this configuration?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This method does not work? Even in an .htaccess file?

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from 93.176.144.153 139.162.206.138
```

Comment: maybe without quote and split
```
        SetEnvif X-Forwarded-For ^93\.176\.144\.153 DenyAccess1
        Deny from DenyAccess1
        SetEnvif X-Forwarded-For ^139\.162\.206\.138 DenyAccess2
        Deny from DenyAccess2
```